# How to show UIImage on Chat bubble with Gloss effect over it

Tags: ios, uiimageview, chat, message, gradient

I am developing a chat application with look and feel of the chat bubbles same as the default iOS app.
I have achieved the text showing and also the Image sowing but its not as per the default iOS message app.I want the Image to be mixed with the Gloss effect of the bubble like attached Image below.

[image]

Will making the transparent Bubble image with gloss will work ?
PLease help!!